# BO 4.0 Webi Variable Editing

Tags: business-objects

I have a variable in a report. This variable has a lot of data in it. How much data can be in the formula field? The reason why I ask is that when I make any changes to this variable the report freezes up. I have recently changed over to BO 4.0 from 3.1 XI.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limitation, however complex formulas can indeed slow down the report (refresh)!
If possible try to insert the formula in an object in the universe and try to push it towards the database layer. The database will handle these kind of requests much better than the report engine of BO.